# In Outlook, how can I be alerted to new messages for just one, not all, email accounts?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

MS Outlook's 'Message arrival' appears to apply to all inboxes indiscriminately, and doesn't let you dis-engage certain inboxes. What if I desire 'Message arrival' alerts for just email 1?

[image]

[image]

Screeen-shots : [Top](https://www.technipages.com/outlook-mail-notification-box), [Bottom](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fi.ytimg.com%2Fvi%2FY5AjtsxSkjA%2Fmaxresdefault.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DY5AjtsxSkjA&docid=rENFpDUmXvaDNM&tbnid=yycMgcexWbRYoM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwjc0d7YoublAhVJR60KHfuRAcAQMwhOKAkwCQ..i&w=1280&h=720&client=firefox-b-d&bih=488&biw=1088&q=outlook%202019%20multiple%20emails&ved=0ahUKEwjc0d7YoublAhVJR60KHfuRAcAQMwhOKAkwCQ&iact=mrc&uact=8).

Comment: A workaround might be to use something like Windows Sandbox, but that would require you to fully configure Outlook, each time you launched it (including syncing your emails).  The option in question is global and applies to all inboxes attached to your single Outlook profile.  You **might** be able to launch multiple instances of Outlook by using 3 different profiles, but I don't believe, Outlook will allow you to do that.  **Basically, what you want, is not possible with Outlook.**

Answer (score 0):

There is not a direct setting for this in Outlook, but you can achieve this by disabling the generic option to display the New Mail Desktop Alert and then create a rule to display it again when mail arrives via your specified account(s).

1. Click File > Options, in the Outlook Options window, click Mail in the left pane, uncheck the Display a Desktop Alert box in the Message arrival section, and then click the OK button.
   [image]
2. Click Rules > Manage Rules & Alerts under Home tab.
   [image]
3. click the New Rule button

4.create rule as follows:

[image]

5. From now on, new email notification will pop up when email arrives in all accounts except the specified one.

Reference: [Disable New Mail Desktop Alert for specific accounts](https://www.msoutlook.info/question/disable-new-mail-alert-for-specific-accounts)